# Entity query - using parent/grandparent ids as a condition

Tags: 8, entities, database

I have relationships linking a node to a child paragraph, with a grandchild paragraph:

```
Node
 |_ paragraph child
        |_ paragraph grandchild
```

Using an entityQuery, I can get child items using `parent_id` as the field/property:

```
return  $this->paragraphStorage->getQuery()
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('type', 'paragraph_grandchild')
  ->condition('parent_id', $paragraph_child_ids, 'IN') 
  ->execute();
```

My problem is that I want to get all grandchildren, but don't want to run 2 queries, and I can't see how to get use the `node` ID as a condition like I do with `parent_id`.

For example (**this doesn't work**):

```
return  $this->paragraphStorage->getQuery()
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('type', 'paragraph_grandchild')
  ->condition('parent_id.entity.parent_id', $node_ids, 'IN') 
  ->execute();
```